# Does all bluetooth modules support RFCOMM?

Tags: bluetooth

I am about to order a Bluetooth module and I wonder if [RFCOMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFCOMM#Radio_frequency_communication_.28RFCOMM.29) is such a basic feature that it is always (or close to always) supported in Bluetooth modules?

Let's say for Bluetooth 2.0+.

Previously this has never been a problem, and it have always been there, but this might be good to know.

Comment: You have to check features on a case-by-case basis, if you have any doubts (if no doubts, you wouldn't be asking here either).  Download the datasheet, look inside, call manufacturer's application support if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the module. There are absolutely no guarantees, because the modules contain their own embedded microcontroller and firmware which provides services.

You can get modules which have enough of the stack in their onboard processor that they do take care of RFCOMM and present as a serial port.  There are other modules (which are more flexible) and require the micro to talk something like BCSP and take care of the higher level functions such as L2CAP and RFCOMM.

You need to carefully look at the datasheet for the specific module you are looking at buying, and be especially careful because most of these chips are all identical except for the software running on them.